# How to check JavaScripts values into a rails variable

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have JavaScripts variables which I got as username and password, I want to check them out if they are okay then show me a new link or new page if not then show me a text.

```
!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function validateForm()
{
var x=document.forms["myForm"]["fname"].value;
}
if (x == "n/a_17") 
{
window.location="http://cmpt470.csil.sfu.ca:8017/welcome/index ";
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<form name="myForm" action="demo_form.asp" onsubmit="return validateF$
User Name: <input type="text" name="username">
Password: <input type="text" name="fname">
<input type="submit" value="Submit"> 
</form>

<% if x == "n/a_17 -%>
password is correct
 <a href="/posts/new"> posts </a>
<% end -%>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: why can't you submit the form and return the answer (link or text) according to that?

Comment: I am very beginner in Rails, how can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your comments, if you're only trying to do an authentication form with Rails, you should check out first the [Rails Tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/), [Chapter 7](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/sign-up#top) is about building an authentication form.

You might also want to check the [Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/).